# How to declare an array of functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers, declaration

Suppose I want to declare an array of functions, and try the following

```cpp
int (*funcs)(int, int)[10];
```

But turns out that the following declaration stands for an function returning an array, which does not compile.

How can I declare an array of functions properly?

Comment: Or use `std::function`, `std::vector<std::function<int(int, int)>>`

Comment: try this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4639/ I've tried its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking you may not declare an array of functions. You may declare an array of function pointers.

It seems you mean

```
int (*funcs[10])(int, int);
```

Another way is to introduce a using declaration (or a typedef declaration) like for example

```
using FP = int( * )( int, int );

FP funcs[10];
```

or

```
using FUNC = int ( int, int );

FUNC * funcs[10];
```

Comment: The third option seems a little bit weird.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan It has its own advantages because the same name FUNC you can using to declare a function and a function pointer..

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
int (*funcs[10])(int, int);
```

Or ask help of `using` (or `typedef`).

```
using fp = int (*) (int, int);
fp funcs[10];
```